# Force From Distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, simulations

I'm working on a physics engine for a game and I need something clarified.

Let's say I have a stationary sphere, sitting atop a platform. The sphere's mass is 10kg, and gravity is $10m/s^2$, for the sake of simplicity. That means that, due to $W = mg = F$, it is exerting a force of 100N on the platform.

Now, imagine the sphere being 100m above the platform, with starting velocity of 0m/s. For simplicity's sake, I'm ignoring drag. Using $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$, the final velocity when it reaches the platform is 63m/s. Now let's say that the time of impact between the sphere and platform is 0.2s, would I be correct if I use $F = m (v-u)/t$ to prove that more force is being exerted on the platform than in the first case?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep with your for simplicity's sake =p, let's say the force exerted on the platform while the ball is in contact with the platform is always the average force; that is, at no point in time while the ball is in contact with the surface is the force greater than any other point in time it is in contact with the surface.

Let's also assume the surface to be 100% elastic (elasticity coefficient of 1), so that the ball would bounce exacty as high as when it began (100 meters). Then when the ball leaves the surface, it must have a veloctiy $v = 63$ m$/$s. That means it's change in momentum $p = \Delta v \cdot m$  and since $\Delta v = 63 \cdot 2 = 126$ (since it orginally was going *down* with 63 m$/$s and now is going *up* with 63 m$/$s) then we have $p = 1260$. Now force $F_{avg} = \Delta p/\Delta t$ (note only use this for a constant force, otherwise we need calculus).

Expanding, we get $F = m(v_{f} - v_{i})/t$ which I believe is exactly what you have

Comment: Sorry, forgot about it :P Marked it!